# Finding values w.r.t. one parameter out of many and making a plot

Tags: plotting, iterators

```
μ = 0.15;
λ = 0.4;
ρ = 1;
r = 0.04;
i = 3;
θ = 1;
κ = 0.1;
σ = 0.15;
γ[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] = 
  (2 κ - 2 μ + 2 λ ρ σ + σ^2 + Sqrt[8 r σ^2 + (-2 κ + 2 μ - 2 λ ρ σ - σ^2)^2])/(2 σ^2);
b[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] = 
  2 - 2 γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] + 2 (κ - μ + λ ρ σ)/σ^2;
B[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] = 
  -Gamma[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]*
   Gamma[b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/
   Gamma[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/
   Gamma[2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]];
h[V] = Hypergeometric1F1[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];
g[V] = 
  Hypergeometric1F1[
    1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], 2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], 
    (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];
F[A, V] = 
  A*(h[V] + B[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]*((2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V))^(1 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r])*g[V])*
  V^γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r];
x = V /. FindRoot[{F[A, V] == V - i, D[F[A, V], V] == 1}, {A, 0.01}, {V, 1.01}]
```

I think this should be an easy question, but I am new to *Mathematica* and can not figure it out.

Variable `x` is what I would like to obtain, and given the parameters values at the beginning of the code, the value of `x` can be found. It should be 6.3632.

Here is the question: how can I change the code and establish a loop to evaluate the values of `x` with σ taking different values, like ranging from 0.1 to 0.2 in step of 0.01. Thus, σ is no longer a constant input as presented in my code but a iterating variable. Also, if it is convenient, how can I plot `x` against the values of σ?

Comment: Do you really need to introduce `x` at all? Don't you really want `V` as a function of `σ`?

Comment: `values = Table[V /. ...., {\[Sigma], 0.1, 0.2, 0.01}]` is a good way to get a list of values, but you may need to define your 'functions' using `:=`...

Comment: Another piece of advice, rewrite your auxiliary expression as functions of `σ`. For example; `With[{κ = κ, μ = μ, ..., r = r}, b[σ_] := 2 - 2 γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] + 2 (κ - μ + λ ρ σ)/σ^2`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way -> take out $\sigma$, put everything in a `Table` and use $\sigma$ as the loop variable. It will make a Table of {$\sigma$,x}.

```
Table[μ = 0.15;
λ = 0.4;
ρ = 1;
r = 0.04;
i = 3;
θ = 1;
κ = 0.1;
                 (*no sigma*)  
γ[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] = (2 κ - 2 μ + 2 λ ρ σ + σ^2 + Sqrt[8 r σ^2 + (-2 κ + 2 μ - 2 λ ρ σ - σ^2)^2])/(2 \σ^2);

b[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] = 2 - 2 γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] + 2 (κ - μ + λ ρ σ)/σ^2;

B[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_,r_] = -Gamma[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]*Gamma[b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/Gamma[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/Gamma[2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]];

h[V] = Hypergeometric1F1[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r],    b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ,r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];

g[V] = Hypergeometric1F1[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ,r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], 2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];

F[A, V] = A*(h[V] + B[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]*((2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V))^(1 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r])*g[V])*   V^γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r];

x = V /.FindRoot[{F[A, V] == V - i, D[F[A, V], V] == 1}, {A, 0.01}, {V, 1.01}], {σ, 0.1, 0.2, 0.01}];

ListPlot[%]
```

**Another way** is to define `x` as a function of $\sigma$. In that way you can use x[$\sigma$] in your calculation.

```
μ = 0.15;
λ = 0.4;
ρ = 1;
r = 0.04;
i = 3;
θ = 1;
κ = 0.1;

γ[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_]:= (2 κ - 2 μ + 2 λ ρ σ + σ^2 + Sqrt[8 r σ^2 + (-2 κ + 2 μ - 2 λ ρ σ - σ^2)^2])/(2 \σ^2);

b[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_]:= 2 - 2 γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] + 2 (κ - μ + λ ρ σ)/σ^2;

B[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_,r_] := -Gamma[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]*Gamma[b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/Gamma[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/Gamma[2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]];

h[V_, σ_] := Hypergeometric1F1[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r],    b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ,r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];

g[V_, σ_] := Hypergeometric1F1[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ,r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], 2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];

F[A_, V_, σ_] = A*(h[V, σ] + B[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]*((2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V))^(1 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r])*g[V, σ])*   V^γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r];

x[σ_] := V /.FindRoot[{F[A, V, σ] == V - i, D[F[A, V, σ], V] == 1}, {A, 0.01}, {V, 1.01}];
```

Now

```
Plot[x[σ],{σ,0.1,0.2}]
```

Or put it in a table.

### Notebook File

Considering the length, I don't feel very confident about my typing. You can use this [Nick.nb](http://db.tt/6I7l0DsG) file if you face any problem in executing what I have written above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
μ = 0.15;
λ = 0.4;
ρ = 1;
r = 0.04;
i = 3;
θ = 1;
κ = 0.1;
γ[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] =
  (2 κ - 2 μ + 2 λ ρ σ + σ^2 + Sqrt[8 r σ^2 + (-2 κ + 2 μ - 2 λ ρ σ - σ^2)^2])/(2 σ^2);
b[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] = 
  2 - 2 γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] + 2 (κ - μ + λ ρ σ)/σ^2;
B[κ_, μ_, λ_, ρ_, σ_, r_] =
  -Gamma[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]*
  Gamma[b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/Gamma[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]]/Gamma[
  2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]];
h[V] =
  Hypergeometric1F1[-γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];
g[V] =
  Hypergeometric1F1[1 - γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r] - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r], 2 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, 
  r], (2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V)];
F[A, V] =
  A*(h[V] + B[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r]*((2 κ θ)/(σ^2 V))^(1 - b[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r])*g[V])*
  V^γ[κ, μ, λ, ρ, σ, r];
```

See that I've defined all variables, expect σ.

Now you can solve it through this command:

```
x = V /. FindRoot[{F[A, V] == V - i /. σ -> #, 
      D[F[A, V], V] == 1 /. σ -> #}, {A, 0.01}, {V, 1.01}] & /@ Range[.1, .2, .01]
```

> {8.65089, 7.9194, 7.36981, 6.94866, 6.62103, 6.3632, 6.15855, 5.99512, 5.86412, 5.75898, 5.67468}

Now you can plot it:

```
ListLinePlot[x, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]